# Why does this code log 10 repeatedly?

Tags: javascript, typescript

this example is given in official documentation of typescript but I cant understand it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 100 * i);
}
```

ouptput of this snippet is:

```
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

Comment: Related to/duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1063392

Comment: Simplest fix is `var` -> `let`, assuming browser properly supports ES6 lexical scope

Comment: but I cant understand if the value of i is increased to 10 in 1st output after that why its repeating 10 times.

Comment: 1. The loop creates 10 functions to be executed with increasing delay. Fi will be executed after i * 100 ms and will log value i. So at the end we have 10  functions to be executed after 0, 100, ... 900ms.
2. Each function will print value i, but because the for loop was executed earlier the value of i is equal to 10